# Calcuate sum of all items based on their status and itemname

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop

Gurus, 
It might be a simple question for you guys, I am not able to figure out the issue so far.

I want to calcualte  Total amount from TABLENAME, based on username and itemname. This code below calculates it well.

> $item_name ( name1, name2, name3 , ... nameN)

```
    for ($i=0;$i<=count($item_name);$i++) 
    {
    if ($item_status[$i] != 0)  {

    $sqloverall=$Db1->query("SELECT  SUM(amount) as usramount FROM 
TABLENAME WHERE user_name='$user_name' and item_name='$item_name[$i]'");
    $temp=$Db1->fetch_array($sqloverall);
    $overall[]=$temp[usramount];
```

> This runs successfully . I get values into $overall[] .. I do some
>   extra calcuations with if condition.

```
if ( condition)   
{
//run this code // some calcuations
$profit= ($overall[$i] * 8970 )/100
 }

else  
{
//run this code  // some calcuations
$profit= ($overall[$i] * 1254 )/100
}
}
}
```

**Question:**
I also need to calculate  `$overall[]=$temp[usramount];` into single variable . so that i can display it outside for loop.
at the moment it displays values like this

> $overall[0] $overall[1] $overall[N]

Kindly guide me how to combine `$overall[$i]` into single variable that can be displayed outside for loop

> final output : Calcuate sum of all items based on their status and
>   user_name , some  item status might be disabled.

Edit1:

I need to SUM  $overall[] and display outside for loop. 
`$var = SUM($overall[]) ;`  this what is actually needed.

i.e.

> combine $overall[0] , $overall[1] , $overall[2],  $overall[N] ,

into single variable as sum of all data and display it.

Comment: Why not just use `$overall[$i]`?

Comment: it will be needing another for loop to display the values .. i want to combine it in single variable

Comment: What single variable do you want? `$var = $overall[$i]` or what?

Comment: anything =  $overall[$i] .. idea is combine $overall[$i] values into single variable

Comment: So what is the problem with `$var = $overall[$i]`?

Comment: i tired it .. but it saves one value only.. it does not add SUM($overall[$i]). 
$var = SUM($overall[$i]), this is what i need

Comment: Absolutely unclear, what is `SUM`? Edit your question please, explain what is the purpose of your actions. Otherwise this is unclear.

Comment: And please format your code.

Comment: Amazing how well search engines work for people who need something that is provided out of the box. :/ Let's see [`I want to sum array elements together in PHP`](https://www.google.com/search?q=I+want+to+sum+array+elements+together+in+PHP). What is the first result you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need sum of all elements of array - there's [`array_sum`](http://php.net/array_sum) function:

```
$total = array_sum($overall);
```

Comment: You see that all your big question can be replaced with several words?

Comment: thats right... i was not getting the idea... that why i had to explain whole thing and write all code here